# Banshee stops working after 1 song

Tags: sound, music, banshee

I can't find real reason banshee stops playing and crashes after 1 song (sometimes after 2/3/4 songs, but 90% after 1 song and on fist few seconds of the 2nd song).
Shuffle on/off doesn't really matter.
I tried to
     sudo apt-get purge remove banshee
     rm -rf ~/.config/banshee-1
     sudo apt-get install banshee
But still have same problem.

`banshee --debug` output:
Normal song (1st):

```
[1 Debug 01:25:56.790] (libbanshee:player) bp_stop: setting state to GST_STATE_NULL
[1 Debug 01:25:56.826] Player state change: Playing -> Idle
[1 Debug 01:25:56.828] Player state change: Idle -> Loading
[1 Debug 01:25:56.924] Player state change: Loading -> Loaded
[1 Debug 01:25:56.926] (libbanshee:player) [gapless] Triggering track-change signal
[1 Debug 01:25:56.927] Player state change: Loaded -> Playing
[1 Debug 01:25:57.942] TrackInfoDisplay RenderAnimation: 32.00 FPS
```

2nd song:

```
[1 Debug 01:26:02.151] Querying model for track to play in song:Next mode
[1 Debug 01:26:02.162] (libbanshee:player) bp_stop: setting state to GST_STATE_NULL
[1 Debug 01:26:02.202] Player state change: Playing -> Idle
[1 Debug 01:26:02.204] Player state change: Idle -> Loading
[1 Debug 01:26:02.317] Player state change: Loading -> Loaded
[1 Debug 01:26:02.319] (libbanshee:player) [gapless] Triggering track-change signal
[1 Debug 01:26:02.327] Opening http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beck
[1 Info  01:26:02.352] Uncached artwork size 37 requested
[1 Debug 01:26:02.353] Player state change: Loaded -> Playing
Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Application.gtk_main () <IL 0x0000e, 0xffffffff>
  at Gtk.Application.Run () <IL 0x00000, 0x0000b>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Run () <IL 0x0000d, 0x0005f>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup () <IL 0x0000f, 0x00049>
  at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup.Startup (Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup/StartupInvocationHandler) <IL 0x00045, 0x0008e>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup<T> () <IL 0x00036, 0x0006b>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup<T> (string[]) <IL 0x0004d, 0x000ff>
  at Nereid.Client.Main (string[]) <IL 0x00001, 0x00017>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (System.AppDomain,System.Reflection.Assembly,string[]) <IL 0x0001b, 0xffffffff>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssemblyInternal (System.Reflection.Assembly,string[]) <IL 0x0002f, 0x00047>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,string[]) <IL 0x0000b, 0x00037>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,string[]) <IL 0x0003b, 0xffffffff>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string) <IL 0x00004, 0x0001f>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string) <IL 0x00039, 0xffffffff>
  at Booter.Booter.BootClient (string) <IL 0x00024, 0x0006b>
  at Booter.Booter.Main () <IL 0x000f6, 0x001db>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0004c, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

    banshee() [0x4961e9]
    banshee() [0x4e6d1f]
    banshee() [0x41dcb7]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfbd0) [0x7ffd5f623bd0]

Debug info from gdb:

Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No threads.

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted
```

SW:

```
# uname -a
Linux drey-ISP-note 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 15 Olivia \n \l
```

HW: ASUS K56B

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Edit > Preferences** and Turn off *Enable Gapless Playback*

This has worked for multiple people affected by a similar problem in fall 2018.  It's probably a separate bug and should be filed against the banshee package.

The problem is possibly identified by playback interruptions that are accompanied by the following debug output:

```
[18 Debug 17:36:19.466] (libbanshee:player) [Gapless] Requesting next track
[1 Debug 17:36:19.756] Querying model for track to play in song:Next mode
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a source of problem - Wiki extension. If I disable wiki - everything's fine.
In menu:

```
Edit -> Preferences -> Extensions -> unmark Wikipedia -> OK
```

But the question is - why it behaves like that and how can we fix it?

Comment: I would guess that banshee is trying to connect to wikipedia for artist data and failing to find it or hanging on a network failure. This did fix it for me though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as the OP.  At first I thought unchecking the wiki extension fixed it because I was able to get to another song, but eventually it quit on me again as well when it shifted to another track. My next step was to check the updates and I saw a new version of the network manager package.  After I installed that one, Banshee began working fine for me again, no issues.